# I have a problem solving this differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$xdy-ydx=\left(x^2+y^2\right)dx$$

How can I solve this differential equation? which type is this equation?
I don't think it is separable and I don't think it's linear too, but it might be homogenous or exact maybe!

I tried to take partial derivatives of them by splitting them into $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ to know if it's exact or not, but I didn't get any solutions.

which type this equation is and what's the answer with steps, please!

Comment: Note that by dividing both sides by $dx$ and rearranging you can rewrite this as: $$xy'-y(y+1)=x^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Substituting $$y(x)=xv(x)$$ then we get $$\frac{d v(x)}{dx}=v(x)^2+1$$
Can you finish?
From $$y=xv(x)$$ we get $$x(v(x)+xv'(x))-xv(x)=x^2+x^2v(x)$$

Comment: I do not understand please make it clearer, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Introducing polar coordinates, $x = r \cos\alpha, \ y = r \sin\alpha,$ we have
$$
dx = dr \cos\alpha - r \sin\alpha \, d\alpha, 
\quad 
dy = dr \sin\alpha + r \cos\alpha \, d\alpha,
$$
which with a partial substitution into the differential equation gives
$$
r^2 \, d\alpha = r^2 dx
.
$$

Thus, for $r \neq 0,$ we have $d\alpha = dx.$ This can easily be solved:
$$x = x_0 + \alpha.$$

Now, 
$$
y = x \tan\alpha = (x_0 + \alpha) \tan(\alpha).
$$

Thus,
$$\begin{align}
x &= x_0+\alpha, \\
y &= (x_0+\alpha) \tan\alpha,
\end{align}$$
where we can consider $\alpha$ be a parameter.